# To introduce a hot topic, "increased interest" vs. "increasing interest"

Tags: word-usage

I want to convey a specific field has gain a
lot of interest. Should I say

- "something becomes an increased interest"

  or
- "something becomes an increasing interest"?

Are there any grammatical errors or better expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, neither of your suggestions are idiomatic. You have an interest *in* something, so the correct way to express this would be:

> There has been increased interest in [something].

or

> Interest in [something] has increased.